# Zener diode identification

Tags: lamp

I need to replace the zener diode. Will the model marked in the table in the picture be correct? The marking method indicates that the diode manufacturer is: "DIODES INCORPORATED".

I do not understand why the SMAJ15 diode requires 15V, while this system is powered by 12V ?

The board comes with a Xioami Bedside Lamp 2.

[image]

Comment: One use for a 15V zener in a 12V app would be over-voltage protection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMAJ series are not zener diodes. They are [TVS: Transient Voltage Suppressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient-voltage-suppression_diode) diodes. These are meant to conduct electricity when the voltage on the DC input is beyond a set limit: in your case 15V with the SMAJ15.

What this prevents is spikes of voltage beyond 15V from reaching your lamp. Anything more than 16.7V will trigger a breakdown. If there is too much current or voltage, this will short out and break the fuses on either the board or the power source.

You always want a TVS diode that is slightly higher rated in voltage than your operating voltage, to prevent unneeded suppression.

The 15V SMAJ15 is the ideal TVS diode for your application. **I'd check your power supply though, since this doesn't break without a reason.**

Comment: If so, great. Thanks for the clarification. I order this SMAJ15

Everything is fine with the adapter. The failure arose as a result of connecting the wrong adapter, which gave 27 V and burned the diode. It's good that the system has such protection because there is hope that after replacing the diode it will still work.